# In MIPS assembly, how do we know what function the opcode refers to if it starts with 000000?

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code, opcode

Sorry for this stupid question.

For example, if I have 0x00812022 why is it

SUB $a0, $a0, $at

And not

ADD $a0, $a0, $at

According to the MIPS reference data, it says

add Opcode: 0/20 Hex

sub Opcode: 0/22 Hex

How do I differentiate between all opcodes that start with 000000?

Comment: Is your mips configured as little or big endian?  Would switching endian-ness change the opcode value?  Try assembling both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R-type instructions have a `funct` field which further specifies the operation.

[image: R-type encoding]

> add Opcode: 0/20 Hex

This means the `op` field is zero, and the `funct` field is 0x20.

Comment: @RetardedProgrammer 100010 is 22 in hexadecimal, which is generally used instead of decimal for this sort of thing (it's easy to convert to binary and back)

Comment: Thank you, now I get it!